# Add Framelabel for ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting

I understand that Framelabel property does not work for ListLogLinearPlot. How we can add axis label with ListLogLinearPlot?

Comment: you need to add the option `Frame ->  True` for the option `FrameLabel -> {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}` to work.

Comment: @kglr Perfect! Thank you. If you could add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Pojj, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `Frame -> True` (default is `Frame -> False`) in order for the option settings for `FrameLabel` to take effect:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}], 
 FrameLabel -> {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}]
```

[image]

```
Options[%, Frame]
```

> {Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}}

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}]
```

[image]